# Django migrate db column width

Tags: python, django, postgresql, migration, database-migration

In Django 1.10, [username max length was increased from 30 to 150 characters.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/#abstractuser-username-max-length-increased-to-150)  I have a django 1.9 app I'd like to migrate to take advantage of this.

I have upgraded the Django installation to 1.10.  When I `python manage.py makemigrations`, I get no changes detected.

If I try to just edit an existing username to be more than 30 characters, I get `django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(30)` in the logs.

I would prefer to use Django's built-in migrations to handle this without hacking around in postgres.  How can I trigger a migration to modify the DB column width?

I had the idea to add a throwaway field to a model, migrate, and remove it again, but that seems hacky, and it seems like there should be a way to handle it better than that.

The Django docs seem silent on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a throwaway field to a model, running `makemigrations`, removing the field, running `makemigrations` again, then running `migrate`.  I got this message:

```
Running migrations:
  Applying foo.0033_userprofile_throwaway... OK
  Applying foo.0034_remove_userprofile_throwaway... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
```

So maybe there was some better way to do it.  At any rate, after the migration I modified a username to be more than 30 chars and it executed just fine.